# circular fisheye distortion rotated 270 deg clocwise or 90 deg anticlockwise before distorted?

Tags: android, bitmap, fisheye, distortion

I've an app that distorts a circle on a bitmap with a fisheye distortion. the circle seems to be rotated 180 deg as well as distorted. Any ideas? there's no clue to me as to why in the filter class. thanks Matt.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import com.tecmark.HorizontalSlider.OnProgressChangeListener;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.Shader.TileMode;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class TouchView extends View{


    private File tempFile;
    private byte[] imageArray;
    private Bitmap bgr;
    private Bitmap bm;
    private Bitmap bgr2 = null;;
    private Paint pTouch;
    private int centreX = 1;
    private int centreY = 1;
    private int radius = 50;
    private int Progress;
    private static final String TAG = "*********TouchView";
    private Filters f = null;

    public TouchView(Context context) {
        super(context);
       // TouchView(context, null);
    }




    public TouchView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context,attr);




        tempFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
                getAbsolutePath() + "/"+"image.jpg");

        imageArray = new byte[(int)tempFile.length()];


     try{

            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(tempFile);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);


            int i = 0;

            while (dis.available() > 0) {
            imageArray[i] = dis.readByte();
            i++;
            }

            dis.close();

       } catch (Exception e) {

               e.printStackTrace();
            }



        BitmapFactory.Options bfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bfo.inSampleSize = 1;

        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageArray, 0, imageArray.length, bfo);
        bgr = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), bm.getConfig());
        bgr = bm.copy(bm.getConfig(), true);
        bgr2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), bm.getConfig());



      f = new Filters();
      //bgr2 = f.barrel(bgr,0.00022F);

        pTouch = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);         
        pTouch.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_OUT)); 
        pTouch.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        pTouch.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);


    }// end of touchView constructor


    public void findCirclePixels(){ 



    /*  for (int i=centreX-50; i < centreX+50; ++i) {
            for (int y=centreY-50; y <centreY+50 ; ++y) {

    if( Math.sqrt( Math.pow(i - centreX, 2) + ( Math.pow(y - centreY, 2) ) ) <= radius ){

                    bgr.setPixel(i,y,Color.rgb(Progress+50,Progress,Progress+100));
                }
            }
        }*/
        float prog = (float)Progress/2000000;
        bgr2 = f.barrel(bgr,prog);

        }// end of changePixel()




    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        switch (ev.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

                centreX = (int) ev.getX();
                centreY = (int) ev.getY();
                findCirclePixels();
                invalidate();

                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

                    centreX = (int) ev.getX();
                    centreY = (int) ev.getY();
                    findCirclePixels();
                    invalidate();
                    break;

            }           

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 

                break;

        }
        return true;
    }//end of onTouchEvent





    public void initSlider(final HorizontalSlider slider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "******setting up slider*********** ");
        slider.setOnProgressChangeListener(changeListener);
    }



    private OnProgressChangeListener changeListener = new OnProgressChangeListener() {


        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(View v, int progress) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            setProgress(progress);
            Log.e(TAG, "***********progress = "+Progress);

        }
    };





    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);


        canvas.drawBitmap(bgr2, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.drawCircle(centreX, centreY, radius,pTouch);



    }//end of onDraw




    protected void setProgress(int progress2) {
        this.Progress = progress2;
        findCirclePixels();
        invalidate();

    }


}
```

.

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.util.Log;

class Filters{
    float xscale;
    float yscale;
    float xshift;
    float yshift;
    int [] s;
    private String TAG = "Filters";
    public Filters(){

        Log.e(TAG, "***********inside constructor");
    }

    public Bitmap barrel (Bitmap input, float k){
        Log.e(TAG, "***********inside barrel method ");
        float centerX=input.getWidth()/2; //center of distortion
        float centerY=input.getHeight()/2;

        int width = input.getWidth(); //image bounds
        int height = input.getHeight();

        Bitmap dst = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,input.getConfig() ); //output pic
        Log.e(TAG, "***********dst bitmap created ");
          xshift = calc_shift(0,centerX-1,centerX,k);
          float newcenterX = width-centerX;
          float xshift_2 = calc_shift(0,newcenterX-1,newcenterX,k);

          yshift = calc_shift(0,centerY-1,centerY,k);
          float newcenterY = height-centerY;
          float yshift_2 = calc_shift(0,newcenterY-1,newcenterY,k);

          xscale = (width-xshift-xshift_2)/width;
          yscale = (height-yshift-yshift_2)/height;
          Log.e(TAG, "***********about to loop through bm");
          /*for(int j=0;j<dst.getHeight();j++){
              for(int i=0;i<dst.getWidth();i++){
                float x = getRadialX((float)i,(float)j,centerX,centerY,k);
                float y = getRadialY((float)i,(float)j,centerX,centerY,k);
                sampleImage(input,x,y);
                int color = ((s[1]&0x0ff)<<16)|((s[2]&0x0ff)<<8)|(s[3]&0x0ff);
    //            System.out.print(i+" "+j+" \\");

                dst.setPixel(i, j, color);

              }
            }*/

          int origPixel;

          for(int j=0;j<dst.getHeight();j++){
              for(int i=0;i<dst.getWidth();i++){
                 origPixel= input.getPixel(i,j);
                float x = getRadialX((float)i,(float)j,centerX,centerY,k);
                float y = getRadialY((float)i,(float)j,centerX,centerY,k);
                sampleImage(input,x,y);
                int color = ((s[1]&0x0ff)<<16)|((s[2]&0x0ff)<<8)|(s[3]&0x0ff);
    //            System.out.print(i+" "+j+" \\");

                if( Math.sqrt( Math.pow(i - centerX, 2) + ( Math.pow(j - centerY, 2) ) ) <= 85 ){
                dst.setPixel(i, j, color);
                }else{
                    dst.setPixel(i,j,origPixel);
                }
              }
            }
        return dst;
    }

    void sampleImage(Bitmap arr, float idx0, float idx1)
    {
        s = new int [4];
      if(idx0<0 || idx1<0 || idx0>(arr.getHeight()-1) || idx1>(arr.getWidth()-1)){
        s[0]=0;
        s[1]=0;
        s[2]=0;
        s[3]=0;
        return;
      }

      float idx0_fl=(float) Math.floor(idx0);
      float idx0_cl=(float) Math.ceil(idx0);
      float idx1_fl=(float) Math.floor(idx1);
      float idx1_cl=(float) Math.ceil(idx1);

      int [] s1 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_fl,(int)idx1_fl);
      int [] s2 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_fl,(int)idx1_cl);
      int [] s3 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_cl,(int)idx1_cl);
      int [] s4 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_cl,(int)idx1_fl);

      float x = idx0 - idx0_fl;
      float y = idx1 - idx1_fl;

      s[0]= (int) (s1[0]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[0]*(1-x)*y + s3[0]*x*y + s4[0]*x*(1-y));
      s[1]= (int) (s1[1]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[1]*(1-x)*y + s3[1]*x*y + s4[1]*x*(1-y));
      s[2]= (int) (s1[2]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[2]*(1-x)*y + s3[2]*x*y + s4[2]*x*(1-y));
      s[3]= (int) (s1[3]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[3]*(1-x)*y + s3[3]*x*y + s4[3]*x*(1-y));
    }

    int [] getARGB(Bitmap buf,int x, int y){
        int rgb = buf.getPixel(y, x); // Returns by default ARGB.
        int [] scalar = new int[4];
        scalar[0] = (rgb >>> 24) & 0xFF;
        scalar[1] = (rgb >>> 16) & 0xFF;
        scalar[2] = (rgb >>> 8) & 0xFF;
        scalar[3] = (rgb >>> 0) & 0xFF;
        return scalar;
    }

    float getRadialX(float x,float y,float cx,float cy,float k){
      x = (x*xscale+xshift);
      y = (y*yscale+yshift);
      float res = x+((x-cx)*k*((x-cx)*(x-cx)+(y-cy)*(y-cy)));
      return res;
    }

    float getRadialY(float x,float y,float cx,float cy,float k){
      x = (x*xscale+xshift);
      y = (y*yscale+yshift);
      float res = y+((y-cy)*k*((x-cx)*(x-cx)+(y-cy)*(y-cy)));
      return res;
    }

    float thresh = 1;

    float calc_shift(float x1,float x2,float cx,float k){
      float x3 = (float)(x1+(x2-x1)*0.5);
      float res1 = x1+((x1-cx)*k*((x1-cx)*(x1-cx)));
      float res3 = x3+((x3-cx)*k*((x3-cx)*(x3-cx)));

      if(res1>-thresh && res1 < thresh)
        return x1;
      if(res3<0){
        return calc_shift(x3,x2,cx,k);
      }
      else{
        return calc_shift(x1,x3,cx,k);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you point out the relevant parts of that code?  That is a lot to read through.

Comment: @Mayra yep sorry about that i just included the TouchView code to show how the bitmap is created. that class calls the filter's barrel method. The effect does work, i just can't see anything in filter code that would rotate the effect. sorry for being so vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it isn't being rotated 90° and mirrored? That could be caused by transposing your X and Y axes. For example, I see you are calling `buf.getPixel(y, x)` despite [Bitmap's getPixel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixel%28int,%20int%29) taking x and y rather than y and x.

Comment: hi, yes i changed those args around because i was getting an error stating that ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30816): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: y must be < bitmap.height(). I've had this error before and it was because i had the x,y swiched. When i changed them to y,x instead of x,y it cleared the error but rotated/mirrored the effect.

Comment: I see in `sampleImage` you are comparing "idx0" (which seems to be the X value) with getHeight() and "idx1" (which seems to be the Y value) with getWidth(). Try fixing that, and otherwise just trace through your code to make sure your math is right.

Comment: Hi it was the getRadialX() and getRadialY methods that needed the i and j args switching. it works now, so you were close enough for me with switching args. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but as 180 degree rotation around (0,0) is a reflection in x=0 plus a reflection in y=0, I wonder if your `xscale` and `yscale` are coming out negative. I haven't followed the logic any deeper, but maybe stepping through in the debugger or logging those values might throw something up.

Comment: stone Hi, I've taken another picture of a face this time and i could have got the degrees of rotation wrong. it looks like the effect in the middle of the bitmap has either been rotated 270 degrees clockwise or 90 degrees anticockwise if that makes sense. i've logged out the values of xscale and yscale and they have values of 0.3754959 and 0.43945822, so are both positive. thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Thiago here's the updated code as promised. it runs @ about 15 seconds to loop through the bitmap. i'm thinking of displaying the camera image first then using a 2nd bitmap overlay on top. the overlay i could cut down to the size of the effect and then place that over the original image. that way i'll only be looping over 1/3 of the pixels. i'm not sure if that will work:) Have a play with it.

.

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Debug;
import android.util.Log;

class Filters{
    private float xscale;
    private float yscale;
    private float xshift;
    private float yshift;
    private int [] s;
    private int [] scalar;
    private int [] s1;
    private int [] s2;
    private int [] s3;
    private int [] s4;
    private String TAG = "Filters";

    public Filters(){

        Log.e(TAG, "***********inside filter constructor");
        s = new int[4];
        scalar = new int[4];
        s1 = new int[4];
        s2 = new int[4];
        s3 = new int[4];
        s4 = new int[4];
    }

    public Bitmap barrel (Bitmap input, float k,float cenx, float ceny){
        //Log.e(TAG, "***********INSIDE BARREL METHOD ");


        //float centerX=input.getWidth()/2; //center of distortion
        //float centerY=input.getHeight()/2;
        float centerX=cenx;
        float centerY=ceny;

        int width = input.getWidth(); //image bounds
        int height = input.getHeight();

        Bitmap dst = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,input.getConfig() ); //output pic

          xshift = calc_shift(0,centerX-1,centerX,k);

          float newcenterX = width-centerX;
          float xshift_2 = calc_shift(0,newcenterX-1,newcenterX,k);

          yshift = calc_shift(0,centerY-1,centerY,k);

          float newcenterY = height-centerY;
          float yshift_2 = calc_shift(0,newcenterY-1,newcenterY,k);

          xscale = (width-xshift-xshift_2)/width;

          yscale = (height-yshift-yshift_2)/height;



          /*for(int j=0;j<dst.getHeight();j++){
              for(int i=0;i<dst.getWidth();i++){
                float x = getRadialX((float)i,(float)j,centerX,centerY,k);
                float y = getRadialY((float)i,(float)j,centerX,centerY,k);
                sampleImage(input,x,y);
                int color = ((s[1]&0x0ff)<<16)|((s[2]&0x0ff)<<8)|(s[3]&0x0ff);
    //            System.out.print(i+" "+j+" \\");

                dst.setPixel(i, j, color);

              }
            }*/

          int origPixel = 0;
          int []arr = new int[input.getWidth()*input.getHeight()];
          int color = 0;

          int p = 0;
          int i = 0;
          long startLoop = System.currentTimeMillis();

          for(int j=0;j<dst.getHeight();j++){
              for( i=0;i<dst.getWidth();i++,p++){
                 origPixel= input.getPixel(i,j);

                float x = getRadialX((float)j,(float)i,centerX,centerY,k);


                float y = getRadialY((float)j,(float)i,centerX,centerY,k);

                sampleImage(input,x,y);

                 color = ((s[1]&0x0ff)<<16)|((s[2]&0x0ff)<<8)|(s[3]&0x0ff);
    //            System.out.print(i+" "+j+" \\");

                //if( Math.sqrt( Math.pow(i - centerX, 2) + ( Math.pow(j - centerY, 2) ) ) <= 150 ){
                if(  Math.pow(i - centerX, 2) + ( Math.pow(j - centerY, 2) )  <= 12500 ){
                //dst.setPixel(i, j, color);
                    arr[p]=color;
                    //Log.e(TAG, "***********arr = " +arr[i]+" i = "+i);
                }else{
                    //dst.setPixel(i,j,origPixel);
                    arr[p]=origPixel;

                }
              }
            }
          long endLoop = System.currentTimeMillis();
          long dur = endLoop - startLoop;
          Log.e(TAG, "loop took "+dur+"ms");

         Bitmap dst2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(arr,width,height,input.getConfig());
        return dst2;

    }// end of barrel()




    void sampleImage(Bitmap arr, float idx0, float idx1)
    {

       // s = new int [4];
      if(idx0<0 || idx1<0 || idx0>(arr.getHeight()-1) || idx1>(arr.getWidth()-1)){
        s[0]=0;
        s[1]=0;
        s[2]=0;
        s[3]=0;
        return;
      }

      float idx0_fl=(float) Math.floor(idx0);
      float idx0_cl=(float) Math.ceil(idx0);
      float idx1_fl=(float) Math.floor(idx1);
      float idx1_cl=(float) Math.ceil(idx1);

     /* float idx0_fl=idx0;
      float idx0_cl=idx0;
      float idx1_fl=idx1;
      float idx1_cl=idx1;*/

     /* int [] s1 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_fl,(int)idx1_fl);
      int [] s2 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_fl,(int)idx1_cl);
      int [] s3 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_cl,(int)idx1_cl);
      int [] s4 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_cl,(int)idx1_fl);*/

       s1 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_fl,(int)idx1_fl);
       s2 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_fl,(int)idx1_cl);
       s3 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_cl,(int)idx1_cl);
       s4 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_cl,(int)idx1_fl);

      float x = idx0 - idx0_fl;
      float y = idx1 - idx1_fl;

      s[0]= (int) (s1[0]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[0]*(1-x)*y + s3[0]*x*y + s4[0]*x*(1-y));
      s[1]= (int) (s1[1]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[1]*(1-x)*y + s3[1]*x*y + s4[1]*x*(1-y));
      s[2]= (int) (s1[2]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[2]*(1-x)*y + s3[2]*x*y + s4[2]*x*(1-y));
      s[3]= (int) (s1[3]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[3]*(1-x)*y + s3[3]*x*y + s4[3]*x*(1-y));


    }

    int [] getARGB(Bitmap buf,int x, int y){

        int rgb = buf.getPixel(y, x); // Returns by default ARGB.
       // int [] scalar = new int[4];
        scalar[0] = (rgb >>> 24) & 0xFF;
        scalar[1] = (rgb >>> 16) & 0xFF;
        scalar[2] = (rgb >>> 8) & 0xFF;
        scalar[3] = (rgb >>> 0) & 0xFF;
        return scalar;
    }

    float getRadialX(float x,float y,float cx,float cy,float k){

      x = (x*xscale+xshift);
      y = (y*yscale+yshift);
      float res = x+((x-cx)*k*((x-cx)*(x-cx)+(y-cy)*(y-cy)));
      return res;
    }

    float getRadialY(float x,float y,float cx,float cy,float k){

      x = (x*xscale+xshift);
      y = (y*yscale+yshift);
      float res = y+((y-cy)*k*((x-cx)*(x-cx)+(y-cy)*(y-cy)));
      return res;
    }

    float thresh = 1;

    float calc_shift(float x1,float x2,float cx,float k){

      float x3 = (float)(x1+(x2-x1)*0.5);
      float res1 = x1+((x1-cx)*k*((x1-cx)*(x1-cx)));
      float res3 = x3+((x3-cx)*k*((x3-cx)*(x3-cx)));

      if(res1>-thresh && res1 < thresh)
        return x1;
      if(res3<0){
        return calc_shift(x3,x2,cx,k);
      }
      else{
        return calc_shift(x1,x3,cx,k);
      }
    }



}// end of filters class
```